# Is it possible to stream RTSP iptv on ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, video-streaming, live-streaming, iptv

Is it possible to play rstp video&audio on ionic (cordova) ?

If so, how can we accomplish it ?

I want to stream live rstp with my ionic app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With many audio and video features you are dependent on the underlying devices capabilities and rules.

Specifically, iOS devices require you to use HLS at this time, if your app is to work on a mobile network (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW5):

> Requirements for Apps
>
> Warning: iOS apps submitted for distribution in the App Store must conform to these requirements.
>
> If your app delivers video over cellular networks, and the video exceeds either 10 minutes duration or 5 MB of data in a five minute period, you are required to use HTTP Live Streaming. (Progressive download may be used for smaller clips.)
>
> If your app uses HTTP Live Streaming over cellular networks, you are required to provide at least one stream at 64 Kbps or lower bandwidth (the low-bandwidth stream may be audio-only or audio with a still image).
>
> These requirements apply to iOS apps submitted for distribution in the App Store for use on Apple products. Non-compliant apps may be rejected or removed, at the discretion of Apple.

There do exist apps which appear to be able to play RTSP on iOS (e.g. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rtsp-player/id1070125481?mt=8 ) so it is not clear if they comply with the duration size rules above or this is just an example of Apple's 'discretion'.

Android devices should support RTSP (depending on version and possibly model etc) - https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html, although Android media players can be tricky (look through stackoverflow question around video playback on Android).

Comment: anything i can use in ionic to stream audio/video ? does not need to be rtsp like u mentioned ios uses HLS (which im not familiar). what is your recommendation for support live streams in ionic for video especially

Comment: Unfortunately, the best approach is to experiment as things change all the time with browser updates and OS updates. To keep it simple, especially of your videos are short and do not require DRM I would simply test serving static video - there are several test sites that will allow you test this, for example: http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html